# Linq join on parameterized distinct key CASE INSENSITIVE

Tags: vb.net, linq, sorting, merge, case-insensitive

To revisit a previous question with a further stipulation...

Anyone know how to do the following, IGNORING CASE?

```
Dim Matches = From mRows In LinqMasterTable Join sRows In LinqSecondTable _
         On mRows(ThePrimaryKey) Equals sRows(TheForignKey) _
         Order By mRows(ThePrimaryKey) _
         Select mRows, sRows
```

For details about the query and it's functions / usage, the previous post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678858/linq-join-on-parameterized-distinct-key).

**EDIT:**

**Here's the kind of tables we're querying:**

```
LinqMasterTable:
 -------------------------------------
|ThePrimaryKey| Description           |
 -------------------------------------
|Green        | This is a Green apple | 
|GREEN        | This is a Green apple | 
|green        | This is a Green apple | 
|Red          | This is a Red apple   | 
|RED          | This is a Red apple   | 
|red          | This is a Red apple   | 
 -------------------------------------

LinqSecondTable
 --------------------------
|TheForignKey | ApplePrice |
 -------------------------- 
|Green        | $0.90      | 
|Pink         | $0.80      | 
|Red          | $0.85      | 
|Yellow       | $0.79      |
 --------------------------
```

**And here's the desired outcome:**

```
 --------------------------------------
|Green | This is a Green apple | $0.90 |
|GREEN | This is a Green apple | $0.90 | 
|green | This is a Green apple | $0.90 |
|Red   | This is a Red apple   | $0.85 |
|RED   | This is a Red apple   | $0.85 |
|red   | This is a Red apple   | $0.85 |
 --------------------------------------
```

**Unfortunately, the actual (undesired) result is this:**

```
 --------------------------------------
|Green | This is a Green apple | $0.90 |
|Red   | This is a Red apple   | $0.85 |
 --------------------------------------
```

---

**ReEdit:**

---

```
Private Sub LinqTwoTableInnerJoinCaseInsensitive(ByRef qMasterDS As DataSet, _
                                  ByRef qMasterTable As DataTable, _
                                  ByRef qSecondDS As DataSet, _
                                  ByRef qSecondTable As DataTable, _
                                  ByRef qPrimaryKey As String, _
                                  ByRef qForignKey As String, _
                                  ByVal qResultsName As String)

    Dim TheMasterTable As String = qMasterTable.TableName 'Table Name'
    Dim TheSecondTable As String = qSecondTable.TableName 'Table Name'
    Dim ThePrimaryKey As String = qPrimaryKey 'The variable name of the first 'merge on' column'
    Dim TheForignKey As String = qForignKey 'The variable name of the second 'merge on' column'
    Dim TheNewForignKey As String = "" 'For handling duplicate column names'

    MasterTableColumns = GetColumns(qMasterDS, TheMasterTable)
    SecondTableColumns = GetColumns(qSecondDS, TheSecondTable)

    Dim mColumnCount As Integer = MasterTableColumns.Count
    Dim sColumnCount As Integer = SecondTableColumns.Count

    Dim ColumnCount As Integer = mColumnCount + sColumnCount

    Dim LinqMasterTable = qMasterDS.Tables(TheMasterTable).AsEnumerable
    Dim LinqSecondTable = qSecondDS.Tables(TheSecondTable).AsEnumerable

    'Original LINQ Query: (Works, but is case sensitive)'
    Dim Matches = From mRows In LinqMasterTable Join sRows In LinqSecondTable _
         On mRows(ThePrimaryKey) Equals sRows(TheForignKey) _
         Order By mRows(ThePrimaryKey) _
         Select mRows, sRows

    'IntelliSense doesnt see "ToUpper" as available. No errors, but no search results.'
    'Error: Public member "ToUpper" on type "DBNull" not found.'
    'Dim Matches = From mRows In LinqMasterTable Join sRows In LinqSecondTable _'
    '              On mRows(ThePrimaryKey).ToUpper Equals sRows(TheForignKey).ToUpper _'
    '              Order By mRows(ThePrimaryKey) _'
    '              Select mRows, sRows'


    'Message = "Public member "sRows" on type "String" not found."'
    'Dim Matches2 = From mRows In LinqMasterTable _'
                   'From sRows In LinqSecondTable _'
                   'Where String.Equals(mRows(ThePrimaryKey), sRows(TheForignKey), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) _'
                   'Select mRows, sRows'


    'Conversion from type "DBNull" to type "String" is not valid.'
    'Dim Matches = _'
    'LinqMasterTable.AsEnumerable().Join( _'
    'LinqSecondTable.AsEnumerable(), _'
    'Function(mRows) mRows("ThePrimaryKey"), _'
    'Function(sRows) sRows("TheForignKey"), _'
    'Function(mRows As DataRow, sRows As DataRow) New With {mRows, sRows}, _'
    'StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)'

        'Doesnt work at all - multiple errors'
        'Dim Matches2 = _'
        'LinqMasterTable _'
        '    .Join( _'
        '        LinqSecondTable, _'
        '        Function(x) x.Key.ToLower(), _'
        '        Function(x) x.Key.ToLower(), _'
        '        Function(o, i) New With {.ID = o.Key, .Description = o.Value, .Price = i.Value} _'
        '    ).Dump()'


    ' Make sure the dataset is available and/or cleared:'
    If dsResults.Tables(qResultsName) Is Nothing Then dsResults.Tables.Add(qResultsName)
    dsResults.Tables(qResultsName).Clear() : dsResults.Tables(qResultsName).Columns.Clear()

    'Adds Master Table Column Names'
    For x = 0 To MasterTableColumns.Count - 1
        dsResults.Tables(qResultsName).Columns.Add(MasterTableColumns(x))
    Next

    'Rename Second Table Names if Needed:'
    For x = 0 To SecondTableColumns.Count - 1
        With dsResults.Tables(qResultsName)
            For y = 0 To .Columns.Count - 1
                If SecondTableColumns(x) = .Columns(y).ColumnName Then
                    SecondTableColumns(x) = SecondTableColumns(x) & "_2"
                End If
            Next
        End With
    Next

    'Make sure that the Forign Key is a Unique Value'
    If ForignKey1 = PrimaryKey Then
        TheNewForignKey = ForignKey1 & "_2"
    Else
        TheNewForignKey = ForignKey1
    End If

    'Adds Second Table Column Names'
    For x = 0 To SecondTableColumns.Count - 1 'Need error handling for if columnname exists'
        dsResults.Tables(qResultsName).Columns.Add(SecondTableColumns(x))
    Next

    PleaseWait(True) 'Locks controls while processing data'

    'Copy Results into the Dataset:'
    For Each Match In Matches

        'Build an array for each row:'
        Dim NewRow(ColumnCount - 1) As Object

        'Add the mRow Items:'
        For x = 0 To MasterTableColumns.Count - 1
            NewRow(x) = Match.mRows.Item(x)
        Next

        'Add the srow Items:'
        For x = 0 To SecondTableColumns.Count - 1
            Dim y As Integer = x + (MasterTableColumns.Count)
            NewRow(y) = Match.sRows.Item(x)
        Next

        'Add the array to dsResults as a Row:'
        dsResults.Tables(qResultsName).Rows.Add(NewRow)

    Next


    If chkUnique.Checked = True Then
        ReMoveDuplicates(dsResults.Tables(qResultsName), ThePrimaryKey)
    End If

    PleaseWait(False) 'Unlocks controls after processing data'

    If Not chkRetainKeys.Checked = True Then 'Removes Forign Key'
        dsResults.Tables(qResultsName).Columns.Remove(TheNewForignKey)
    End If

    'Clear Arrays'
    MasterTableColumns.Clear()
    SecondTableColumns.Clear()

End Sub
```

**Incidentally, some additional information:**

```
Dim MasterTableColumns As New ArrayList() 'Holds the Names of the Master Table Columns'
Dim SecondTableColumns As New ArrayList() 'Holds the Names of the Second Table Columns'
Dim MasterTable As String 'Current User Selected Master Table'
Dim PrimaryKey As String 'Table 0 User Selected Key'
Dim ForignKey1 As String 'Table 1 User Selected Key'


Private Function GetColumns(ByVal aDataset As DataSet, ByVal aTable As String) As ArrayList

    If aDataset Is Nothing Then Return Nothing

    If Not aDataset.Tables(aTable) Is Nothing Then
        Dim TempArray As New ArrayList()
        For x = 0 To aDataset.Tables(aTable).Columns.Count - 1
            With aDataset.Tables(aTable).Columns(x)
                TempArray.Add(.ColumnName)
            End With
        Next
        Return TempArray
    Else
        MsgBox("There are no column names in the table """ & aTable & """ to load.")
        Return Nothing
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best Solution we could come up with:

[1] Import XLS File1 to Dataset ds1 and XLS File2 to Dataset ds2

[2] Allow user to Select the desired Merge-Using columns

[3] Add UPPER column to ds1 and ds2

[4] Copy Column Data over as Uppercase for both tables:

```
For each dr as DataRow in ds1.Tables(0).Rows
  dr.Item(UPPER) = dr.Item(MixCaps).ToUpper
Next
```

[5] Merge tables using UPPER columns

[6] Delete UPPER columns and output merged table

I know this output doesn't strictly use LINQ to Merge Case Insensitively, however it's the best I could do within the deadline. Thanks for all the help guys. Wish the other ideas would have worked. Meh. Maybe next time.

Party on Wayne. 
Party on Garth.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a `IEqualityComparer<T>` in the join, but you can't do it with the query syntax. You have to use the extension method syntax:

```
Dim Matches = _
    LinqMasterTable.AsEnumerable().Join( _
        LinqSecondTable.AsEnumerable(), _
        Function(mRows) mRows("ThePrimaryKey"), _
        Function(sRows) sRows("TheForeignKey"), _
        Function(mRows As DataRow, sRows As DataRow) New With { mRows, sRows }, _
        StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: InvariantIgnoreCase' is not a member of 'System.StringComparer.

Comment: Results: Nothing || 
Reason: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include the test data and what it is that I'm trying to do. Sorry if I failed to be more clear. I'm a little bummed that LINQ can't simply ignore case.

Comment: It *can* ignore case, it's just not the default behavior, that's why you need to specify which comparer to use. I don't know how you got this error, since the test data you posted doesn't contain any null... Anyway, there were a few mistakes in the code, I fixed them. It works fine with the test data you provided.

Comment: Returns Nothing and says "Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid." Tried doing it without the Quotes: Returns Nothing and says "Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid."

Comment: Where I continue having trouble with this is that I'm using variable key values. Earlier in the program's functions we're opening two Excel files and saving them into memory with whatever column headers the user gave them. The purpose is to merge two files for the user. The example tables given are good examples of what the user might input, but the values for "ThePrimaryKey" and "TheForignKey" are variable. Using "mRows.ThePrimaryKey" doesn't work because the column header will rarely be the same thing twice. Using mRows("ThePrimaryKey") as a fixed string doesn't work for the same reason.

Comment: Think along the lines of msgbox(TheMessage) rather than msgbox("TheMessage")

Comment: OK, so ThePrimaryKey and TheForignKey are variables, not literal strings... but it doesn't explain why it doesn't work. Could you update your question to post the exception stack trace ?

Comment: The Null value strikes me as odd, too, as there are no Null values in the data tables. However, if no match is found, I imagine that would return a null value, would it not?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution joining on the lowercase versions of your keys:

```
LinqMasterTable _
    .Join( _
        LinqSecondTable, _
        Function(x) x.ThePrimaryKey.ToLower(), _
        Function(x) x.TheForignKey.ToLower(), _
        Function(o,i) New With { .ID = o.ThePrimaryKey, .Description = o.Description, .Price = i.ApplePrice } _
    )
```

Testing with your sample data provided the exact results you desired:

LinqPad Test (VB Version):

```
Dim LinqMasterTable = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
LinqMasterTable.Add("Green", "This is a Green apple")
LinqMasterTable.Add("GREEN", "This is a Green apple")
LinqMasterTable.Add("green", "This is a Green apple")
LinqMasterTable.Add("Red", "This is a Red apple")
LinqMasterTable.Add("RED", "This is a Red apple")
LinqMasterTable.Add("red", "This is a Red apple")

Dim LinqSecondTable = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
LinqSecondTable.Add("Green", "$0.90")
LinqSecondTable.Add("Pink", "$0.80")
LinqSecondTable.Add("Red", "$0.85")
LinqSecondTable.Add("Yellow", "$0.79")

LinqMasterTable _
    .Join( _
        LinqSecondTable, _
        Function(x) x.Key.ToLower(), _
        Function(x) x.Key.ToLower(), _
        Function(o,i) New With { .ID = o.Key, .Description = o.Value, .Price = i.Value } _
    ).Dump()
```

Returns:

```
ID     Description            Price 
Green  This is a Green apple  $0.90
GREEN  This is a Green apple  $0.90
green  This is a Green apple  $0.90
Red    This is a Red apple    $0.85
RED    This is a Red apple    $0.85
red    This is a Red apple    $0.85
```

(I wrote and tested in C# so let me know if I screwed anything up converting it to VB!)

Original C#:

```
LinqMasterTable
    .Join(
        LinqSecondTable,
        x => x.ThePrimaryKey.ToLower(),
        x => x.TheForignKey.ToLower(),
        (o,i) => new { ID = o.ThePrimaryKey, Description = o.Description, Price = i.ApplePrice }
    )
```

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get this to work at all. Do you still have the original c# query? I could try re-translating.

Comment: Certainly.  Added C# version.  What error were you getting in VB?

Comment: I went ahead and tested the VB version in LinqPad and it seems to be working for me (see post for test results and code).  Let me know if there are still problems.

Comment: With and Without " Dim Matches2 = _" in front of it, the following errors occur:

Comment: Error 1: Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in extension method 'Public Function Join(Of TInner, TKey, TResult)(inner As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TInner), outerKeySelector As System.Func(Of System.Data.DataRow, TKey), innerKeySelector As System.Func(Of TInner, TKey), resultSelector As System.Func (Of System.Data.DataRow, TInner, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable' cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.

Comment: Error 2, 3, and 4: 'Key' is not a member of 'System.Data.DataRow'.

Comment: Error 5 and 6: 'Value' is not a member of 'System.Data.DataRow'.

Comment: Key and Value are properties off of the dictionary I was using to test.  'Key' should be replaced with whatever it takes to get the values of your primary and foreign keys.  'Value' should be replaced with whatever it takes to get the value of your 'description' and 'price' columns.  They were only 'Key' and 'Value' in my test since I was using a dictionary and not a DataRow.